# Efficient way to check if a specific character in a string appears consecutively

Tags: python-3.x, string

Say the character which we want to check if it appears consecutively in a string `s` is the dot `'.'`.

For example, `'test.2.1'` does **not** have consecutive dots, whereas `'test..2.2a...'` **has** consecutive dots. In fact, for the second example, we should not even bother with checking the rest of the string after the first occurence of the consecutive dots.

I have come up with the following simple method:

```
def consecutive_dots(s):
    count = 0
    for c in data:
        if c == '.':
            count += 1
            if count == 2:
            return True
        else:
            count = 0
    return False
```

I was wondering if the above is the most 'pythonic' and efficient way to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `in` to check if two consecutive dots (that is, the string `".."`) appear in the string `s`

```
def consecutive_dots(s):
    return '..' in s
```